# Alias for 'is' in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'd like to be able to create a symbolic alias for the `is` operator in prolog that can also be used with pack func. So far, I have this:

```
:- use_module(library(func)).
:- op(50, xfy, [$]).
:- op(700, xfx, [#]).
#(X, Y) :- is(Y, X).
```

I can run queries like:

```
?- 2*10+5 # X.
```

But can't run something like:

```
?- write(#$2*10+5).
```

which gives me a syntax error.

How do I get `#` and `$` working together?

Comment: What is `$` supposed to do?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `$` is defined as a meta_predicate in `library(func)`. It provides a functional feel: `X is some_pred$(some_arg).` as opposed to `some_pred(some_arg, X).`. Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

Both `($)/2` and `(#)/2` are *binary* operators:

```
:- op(50, xfy, [$]).
:- op(700, xfx, [#]).
```

So, `#$2*10+5` *must* give syntax errors. `#($(2*10+5))` OTOH works just fine.

Comment: Thanks repeat. I will try that, and see how it goes.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your idea. I can't have `$` as a unary op, as it's defined to be binary in `library(func)`. Also `#($(2*10+5))` does not work for me. It gives me: `ERROR: Arithmetic: '#($ (2*10+5))' is not a function`

Comment: Above `(#)/1` and `($)/1` may not be what you want. Did you expect to use their binary forms?

Comment: Yes, I expect their binary forms but `$` is defined in `library(func)` such that `<binary_predicate/2>($(<first_arg>))` should work. And I know it works if the binary predicate name is a word, like `foo`, in which case `foo$(2*10+5)` would work (and does work) fine. Replace `foo` with a symbol (like `#`) however and...crash.

Comment: @Ash. Syntax error, right?  I see what you want: try  `# $4` or `(#)$4` or `# $ 4`...

Comment: @Ash. Note the blanks (or parentheses) above!